# oprofile - using ocount / operf - LLC miss issue 100%

Tags: performance, caching, oprofile

Host: ubuntu 15.04

oprofile version: 1.1.0

CPU: Intel XEON D-1520

1.

```
./ocount --events=INST_RETIRED,LLC_MISSES,LLC_REFS ./test
```

The result is:

```
Event                Count                    % time counted
INST_RETIRED         1,847,242,162            100.00
LLC_MISSES           306,616,715              100.00
LLC_REFS             306,616,715              100.00
```

The `LLC_MISSES` and `LLC_REFS` is the same which means the cache missing rate is 100%. Why does this happen ? It looks incorrect to me.

And I use `operf` to do the test:

```
sudo operf -e INST_RETIRED:2000003 -e LLC_MISSES:10000 -e LLC_REFS:10000 -e l1d_replacement:2000003 ./test

INST_RETIRED:2...|l1d_replacemen...| LLC_MISSES:10000|   LLC_REFS:10000|
     samples|      %|  samples|      %|  samples|      %|  samples|      %|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
      929 100.000       132 100.000      13083 100.000     13083 100.000 test
    INST_RETIRED:2...|l1d_replacemen...| LLC_MISSES:10000|   LLC_REFS:10000|
      samples|      %|  samples|      %|  samples|      %|  samples|      %|
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
          927 99.7847       132 100.000      13046 99.5721     13046 99.7172 test
```

The `L1D` is relatively fair. However, the `LLC ( Last Level Cache )` cache miss rate is the same as `ocount`, 100%.

I have not found the root cause, please share your experience if you know why or how to fix this.

Thanks